# Does a ticket to Montserrat Mountain include 8 free city rides?

Tags: trains, spain, barcelona

Regarding Barcelona

1) I have heard that a ticket to Montserrat Mountain includes 8 free city rides. Is it so?

2) Are there any activities that runs only on a specific day? E.g. the magic fountain?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know: No.

There are two combined tickets on sale:

- Trans Montserrat: 26,60. This includes transportation from anywhere in
  Zone 1 to Montserrat using the Metro, FGC train and the rack railway,
  outward and back.
- Tot Montserrat: 42,65. Transportation as per Trans
  Montserrat, but with unlimited travel on the local funiculars in
  Montserrat, access to te Museum and a Lunch.

But no free 8 city rides...